# When I enter four digits, "/" will be added, but when I blur, the "/" will disappear

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I enter four digits, "/" will be added, but when I blur, the "/" will disappear. Causes the slash to disappear when entering the number again. What is the reason? Please help me to answer. Thank you

[image]
[image]

```
data(){
birthdayError: '',
birthdayErrMsg: false
},
method:{
birthdayBlur() {
 if (this.birthday.length < 14) {
         this.birthdayError = true
         this.birthdayErrMsg = 'errmsg'
       }
 }
}
birthdayFocus(){
this.birthdayError = false
}

    mounted: function () {
      const inp = document.querySelector('.keypress')
      inp.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
        const key = e.whichc
        if (key !== 8 && key !== 46) {
          if (inp.value.length == 4) {
            inp.value = (inp.value + ' / ');
          } else if (inp.value.length == 9) {
            inp.value = (inp.value + ' / ');
          }
        }
      })
      inp.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        const key = e.which
        if ((key == 8 || key == 46) && inp.value.length === 12) {
          inp.value = inp.value.slice(0, 9)
        } else if ((key == 8 || key == 46) && inp.value.length === 7) {
          inp.value = inp.value.slice(0, 4)
        }
      })
    }
```

```
<input type="text" v-model="birthday" @blur="birthdayBlur" @focus="birthdayFocus"
      class="keypress" maxlength='14' placeholder="YYYY / MM / DD" autocomplete="off"
      inputmode="decimal">
      </div>
      </div>
<div v-show="birthdayError">{{ birthdayErrMsg }}</div>
```

Comment: i think you should use vue instance methods rather than vanilla js, or at least inside eventListeners you should update `birthday` value

Comment: ok i rewrite it to watch, thank you

Comment: you can use @keypress/@keydown as i did in the answer to control your `birthday` variable value

Answer (score 0):

This if is what puts the "/" (slash) after you enter 4 digits/characters.

```
 if (inp.value.length == 4) {
            inp.value = (inp.value + ' / ');
    }
```

And this part of your code is that "dissapears" the slash, by keeping only the first 4 characters in your input

```
else if ((key == 8 || key == 46) && inp.value.length === 7) {
          inp.value = inp.value.slice(0, 4)
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it has nothing to do with this code “else if ((key == 8 || key == 46) && inp.value.length === 7)”, the slash will disappear when I am blur

Comment: but this
```
 inp.value = inp.value.slice(0, 4)
```
is the code that cuts the 5fth character which is the "/" in your case

Answer (score 0):

try to use `@keydown` and `@keypress`.

inside template

```html
<input v-model="birthday" ... @keydown="onKeydown" @keypress="onKeypress" />
```

inside script tag

```js
data() {
  return {
    birthday: '',
    ...
  }
},
methods: {
  onKeypress({ which }) {
    if (![8, 46].includes(which)) {
      if (birthday.length === 4 || birthday.length === 9) {
        birthday += '/'
      }
    }
  },
  onKeydown({ which }) {
    if ([8, 46].includes(which)) {
      if (birthday.length === 12) {
        birthday = birthday.slice(0, 9)
      } else if (birthday.length === 7) {
        birthday = birthday.slice(0, 4)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i hope this fix your issue